# Correctly begin and end an environment via commands

Tags: macros, environments, latex3

I would like to create a set of commands in my recent document class [`jwjournal`](https://ctan.org/pkg/jwjournal) for temporarily switch the syntax off and on. However, when trying to end and start the main environment with commands, this error appears:

```
\begin{jwjournal} on input line 11 ended by \end{{}.
```

Below is a MWE. To my knowledge, `\JournalSyntaxOn` should be equivalent to `\begin{jwjournal}` and similarly for `\JournalSyntaxOff`, but it is clearly not the case here. Is there any chance that my definitions below can somehow be fixed?

```
\documentclass{jwjournal}
\def\JournalSyntaxOn{\begin{jwjournal}}
\def\JournalSyntaxOff{\end{jwjournal}}

\begin{document}

\end{jwjournal}   \verb|test| \begin{jwjournal}  % Works

\JournalSyntaxOff \verb|test| \JournalSyntaxOn   % Error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any change when replacing TeX \def by Latex \newcommand? Anyway, the off-on pattern looks strange, at least unexpected, to me.

Comment: @MS-SPO I don't think that would work. Actually I was writing these commands with `\NewDocumentCommand` and there were also several boolean operations involved, but after realizing the error I simplified it to the most primitive form, and at this point I am not able to tell what is going on here...

Comment: your environment uses the +b argument type. That means it tries to grab the body. Grabbing doesn't expand the body while looking for the end marker and so doesn't work if you hide the end marker inside some command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the explanation! I guess that I would just have to give up this intention then...

Answer (score 1):

You may not be taking the right approach: perhaps you don't need to define a set of two commands, but an *environment*; something like `begin{jwjournalsynt}` and `\end{jwjournalsynt}`. Section 3.4 of [the Old User Guide](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/base/usrguide-historic.pdf) told you how to do this:

```
\newenvironment {⟨cmd⟩} [⟨num⟩] [⟨default⟩] {⟨beg-def ⟩} {⟨end-def ⟩}
\newenvironment* {⟨cmd⟩} [⟨num⟩] [⟨default⟩] {⟨beg-def ⟩} {⟨end-def ⟩}
\renewenvironment {⟨cmd⟩} [⟨num⟩] [⟨default⟩] {⟨beg-def ⟩} {⟨end-def ⟩}
\renewenvironment* {⟨cmd⟩} [⟨num⟩] [⟨default⟩] {⟨beg-def ⟩} {⟨end-def ⟩}
```

now, and section 2.4 of [the New User Guide](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf) tells you

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment {⟨env⟩} {⟨arg spec⟩} {⟨beg-code⟩} {⟨end-code⟩}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment {⟨env⟩} {⟨arg spec⟩} {⟨beg-code⟩} {⟨end-code⟩}
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment {⟨env⟩} {⟨arg spec⟩} {⟨beg-code⟩} {⟨end-code⟩}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment {⟨env⟩} {⟨arg spec⟩} {⟨beg-code⟩} {⟨end-code⟩}
```

@ulrike precisely points out in a comment that you are trying to define a new *environment*, which seems to me is still obscure to you; and that you are dealing with a special case.

```
While environments \begin{⟨environment⟩} . . . \end{⟨environment⟩} are typically used in cases where the code implementing the ⟨environment⟩ does not
need to access the contents of the environment (its ‘body’), it is sometimes
useful to have the body as a standard argument.
This is achieved by ending the argument specification with b, which is a dedicated argument type for this situation. For instance
\NewDocumentEnvironment{twice} {O{\ttfamily} +b}
{#2#1#2} {}
\begin{twice}[\itshape]
Hello world!
\end{twice}
```

You may check how this is done internally (with LaTeX3 syntax), by searching `\__cmd_declare_env:nnnn` in the LaTeX sources.

In any event, this is a LaTeX3 thing, and not a "core" question.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite get your point here. Actually in my class there is already an environment defined with the `+b` type argument, and what I was proposing to do is to have a set of commands to end and restart this environment within its content, to which Ulrike Fischer said that "[it] doesn't work if you hide the end marker inside some command".

Comment: my point, in part, is that once you have the environment, why do you need the pair of css?

Comment: and the other part, is that perhaps you may be trying it backwards: instead of defining `\JournalSyntaxOn` as `\begin{jwjournal}` and `\JournalSyntaxOff` as `\end{jwjournal}` as you did, you could define `\JournalSyntaxOn` and `\JournalSyntaxOff` first, and then define `\NewDocumentEnvironment{jwjournal}{<etc>}{\JournalSyntaxOn}{\JournalSyntaxOff}`.

Comment: The environment I defined grabs its content and then scans and does regex replacements. To hide it from the user, I `\begin` it at `begindocument` and `\end` it at `enddocument`. This, however, prevents the usage of commands like `\verb`, thus it would be necessary to be able to leave this environment in the middle of the document. Regarding your first point, I wish to define the pair of new commands since I don't want the user to write `\end{jwjournal}` and then `\begin{jwjournal}`, which is quite ugly.

Comment: Regarding your second point, it seems very reasonable but for now I don't know an easy way to grab the content between these two commands...

Comment: on (2), perhaps there is none (something to discuss in the LaTeXList); meanwhile, surrounding the `\verb|test|` with `\scantokens` seems to disable the tokenizations done while "grabbing" the document body, and thus partially disables the effects of `jwjournal`.

Comment: so, if you `\let\jwsyntoff\scantokens` you may write `\jwsyntoff{\verb|test|}` and bypass the error, for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that the "jwjournal" enviroment uses the `b` xparse functionality to grab the environment body between the `\begin{...}` and the next `\end{...}`

... in the *document text*, not in the expansion of a macro in the document text.

This means that your `\JournalSyntaxOn` expands to `\begin{jwjournal}` which expands to some internal xparse macros trying to grab everything until an `\end` of the current environment is found.  Because you "hide" the corresponding `\end{...}` inside the `\JournalSyntaxOff` macro there is no `\end` to be found or the wrong `\end` or the end of the document will stop the scan process with an error message.

Thus the simplest solution is to define a normal LaTeX environment on top of "jwjournal" and/or "xparse", already proposed in the other answers and comments.

Or you have to implement your own scan and grab routines to search for `\JournalSyntaxOff` macro token instead of the environment `\end{...}`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations and suggestions. Could you please be a little bit more specific about the "simplest solution"? I didn't quite understand its idea.

Comment: You are the author of the "jwjournal" class and already has implementing the environment body parsing using "xparse" argument type `b`, token list register assignment and parse/regexp functionalities in your class.  I see that you also have hooked into begin/end document if scroll boolean is set accordingly (which is no the best approach because then you end an jwjournal environment without beginning it explicitly and begin one without an explicit end - unbalanced/unmatched envs).  Therefore I assume that you understand the underlying principles and how to extend them on environment level!?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't quite get it, especially regarding the "unmatched envs" part and "extend them on environment level". 1) The `\begin`/`\end` of `jwjournal` is always hooked into begin/end document as I would like to hide the internal of this class from the user, and I assume that you mean this would make the `\begin`/`\end` unbalanced for the user? 2) By "underlying principles" do you mean the mechanism of creating new "scan and grab routines"? From this perspective, I am really just a beginner of the expl3 syntax and knows nothing about its internal realization...

Comment: @Jinwen: 1/ if you embed the `jwjournal` environment in the `document` one, you open the environment implicitly, forcing yourself (or the user) to cancel its effects with an "unbalanced" `\end{jwjournal}`, because there is no explicit `\begin{jwjournal}` to open it; and that is what I collect you describe (correctly) as "ugly" in other comments; and then, 2/ grabbing *the whole document body* for parsing in one go does not sound like a good idea, to begin with: it might be better trying to parse it piecewise some other way.